# How to parse querystring parameter from URL in Fastify server?

Tags: node.js, query-string, request.querystring, querystringparameter, fastify

I am a totally new to fastify but I have a fastify server running. I want to parse query string such as:

```
http://fake.com/?user=123&name=ali
```

I want to get "user" and "name" values from the URL above. My current code is like this:

```
fastify.route({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/',
  handler: async (request, reply) => getCompanyUsers(request, reply, services)
});
```

I want to get values of "user" and "name" and then pass the values to getCompanyUsers function.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can access the querystring using `request.query`

You can look at the official documentation here
https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/main/docs/Reference/Request.md

Answer (score 9):

```
 fastify.route({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/',
 schema: {
   // request needs to have a querystring with a `name` parameter
   querystring: {
    name: { type: 'string' }
  }
   },
   handler: async (request, reply) => {
   // here you will get request.query if your schema validate
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to how you get params in fastify, ie: `request.params.somepathparam`, query is the same:

```
let user = request.query.user
let name = request.query.name
```